# Is it possible to save a string variable in the csv format as a python dataframe WITHOUT first saving a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a string that is in the csv format, and I am wondering whether I can save it as a data frame without first saving it as a csv and then importing it as one.

Thanks!

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.

Comment: @Riceblades btw, there is shorthand built into the side for that link: `[ask]` results in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the possible approaches is to convert the string into a [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) object and pass it to `pd.DataFrame`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

string_data = StringIO("""col1,col2
    1,"a"
    2,"b"
    3,"c"
    4,"d"
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(string_data)
```